# Poisson point distribution

Tags: distributions, homework

The probability of n telephone calls received at an exchange in a time frame (t_i, t_f ) is given by the Poisson point distribution:

```
P(n) = [Lambda(t_f-t_i)]^n/n! e^(t_f - t_i)
```

where Lambda is a constant called the rate parameter.

I want to:

1. Find the expected number of calls in 6 hours (take the unit of time as hours) for a rate parameter of 5.
2. What is the smallest rate parameter such that the probability of 8 or
   fewer calls in 2 hours is no more than 0.9?

For part 1 I tried: `Solve[p /. {tf -> 6, ti -> 0, \[Lambda] -> 5}, n]` and for part 2 I tried `Solve[p /. {n -> 8, tf -> 2, ti -> 0} == 0.9, \[Lambda]]` but I can't seem to figure it out. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen `PoissonDistribution[]`?

Comment: No I've never heard of it. How would I use it in this case?

Comment: Ah, that's where reading about it in the docs would come in...

Comment: @Ccyan as J.M. has expressed look at documentation of `PoissonDistribution` ,esp applications. Also look at `PoissonProcess`. Also your `P(n)` appears incorrect (exponential time) and the round brackets are incorrect syntax for Mathematica.

Comment: So I think I would have to use PDF with PoissonDistribution to get the probability? But what would be the mean in my case?

Comment: Is this homework? And what is E^(abacus)?

Comment: @ciao E^(abacus)? And yes this is homework

Comment: Ok I figured out how to get the probability: `pp = PDF[PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda] (tf - ti)], n]`. Now how would I solve for the first part given tf, ti, and lambda? Should I use solve?

Comment: Then please tag it as such. E^jibberish is what I see in your formula - perhaps you pasted in some character from a character set not commonly supported - I presume it's supposed to be greek lambda and the formula is supposed to be the pdf of the Poisson.

Comment: @ciao Hmm I'm not sure why you are seeing that. It's E^Lambda(t_f - t_i)

Comment: @Ccyan look at the properties of the Poisson distribution and you will not need Mathematica for the first question. You can use Mathematica to get better insight into this distribution. The second question is little trickier.

Comment: @ubpdqn I think part 1 is just 30. For part 2 I tried this but I don't think it was right: `Reduce[pp[\[Lambda]] == 0.9, \[Lambda]]`

Comment: @Ccyan just to be explicit $P(x<=8)=0.9$ <=> `CDF[PoissonDistribution[r],8]==0.9`. You solve for r (or $\lambda$ in your case. Note also if your rate is per hour you need to take that into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was largely dealt with in the comments. I post this for illustrative purposes (but mainly fun):

The following shows use of `PoissonProcess` and its use with `RandomFunction`, `Expectation`, `Probability`. The last line is probability at t=6 that there had been only 1 customer for rate 5/hour:

```
pp = PoissonProcess[5];
rf = RandomFunction[pp, {0, 6}, 1000];
Show[DistributionChart[{, , , , , , rf["LastValues"]}], 
 ListPlot[rf["Paths"], Joined -> True], GridLines -> {None, {30}}]
Expectation[v[6], v \[Distributed] pp]
Histogram[rf["LastValues"]]
Probability[v[6] == 1, v \[Distributed] pp]
```

[image]

Visually confirmation of `Solve`:

```
sol = {r, 8, CDF[PoissonDistribution[2 r], 8]} /. 
   First[Solve[CDF[PoissonDistribution[2 r], 8] == 0.9, r]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[CDF[PoissonDistribution[2 r], x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  GridLines -> {{8}, {0.9}}, Exclusions -> None, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[sol[[{2, 3}]]], 
    Text[sol[[1]], {8, 0.8}]}], {r, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]